# How to add a META tag in head conditionally to entity content

Tags: theming, meta-tags

I need to put a meta NOINDEX tag in head conditionally to a CCK field value ("visibility=private") in one specific content type ("projects").

I read about drupal_add_html_head($data = NULL, $key = NULL) but I'm not sure where to put it.

If I could put the tag in body I would just use a computed_field, but as I need it to be in head, should I put it on my own module (but on which hook?) or should I copy/insert it  in html.tpl.php ?

My problems are (a) that if html.tpl.php will change then I'll have to change also the copy I overridden; (b) then I'm also not sure I have access to $entity inside the template (I never used them) and, finally, (c) that being a matter of logic rather than presentation a module maybe is more indicated than a template.
For all this reasons I would prefer a custom module. Would it be possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's definitely possible, you could do this using [`hook_entity_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view/7) for example:

```
function MYMODULE_entity_view($entity, $type, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($type == 'my_entity_type' && $view_mode == 'some_view_mode') {
    // Check the field items.
    if ($items = field_get_items('my_entity_type', $entity, 'field_visibility')) {
      if ($items[0]['value'] == 'private') {
        $element = array(
          '#tag' => 'meta',
          '#attributes' => array(
            'name' => 'robots',
            'content' => 'noindex',
          ),
        );
        drupal_add_html_head($element, 'robots');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, even more detailed answer than I expected. It works great.